# customize contextmenu and icon on jstree

Tags: icons, contextmenu, jstree

I would like to change default contextmenu and customize the create function with submenus: create service and create application. Then I would also like to associate icons with the service and application submenus.

I searched available solutions on stackoverflow and modified it to suit my requirements. But it does not work.
So far, when I click on submenu the alert box is displayed. But the create node does not work. The icons are not displayed either.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

```
  "contextmenu" : {
    items : { b
        "create" : {
            "separator_before"  : false,
            "separator_after"   : true,
            "label"             : "Create",
            "action"            : false,
            "submenu" :{
                "create_service" : {
                    "seperator_before" : false,
                    "seperator_after" : false,
                    "label" : "service",
        "icon": "service.png",
                    action : function (obj) {
            alert("creating service");
                            this.create(obj, "last", {"attr" : {"rel" : "service"}});
                    }
                },
                "create_application" : {
                    "seperator_before" : false,
                    "seperator_after" : false,
                    "label" : "app",
        "icon": "app.png",
                    action : function (obj) { 
            alert("creating app");                              
                            this.create(obj, "last", {"attr" : { "rel" : "application"}});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

check line 2, and remove the "b":

```
items : { b
```

As an example, a snippet of my contect menu (maybe this helps):

```
"contextmenu": {
    "items": {
        "create" : false,
        "ccp" : false,
        "rename" : false,
        "remove" : {
            "label" : "&nbsp;Delete",
            "icon" : "/images/icon/cross.png"
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Is this a relative path after "icon"? If so, what is the reference path? And if it's absolute, how can I get the absoulte path in a dynamic context?

Comment: I'm using an absolute path, created by the template file. I think you can use a relative path, then you'd have to reference it from the current url since it's "just an image like any other"...

Comment: thanks for coming back to this question... do you happen to know if one can reference icons from a jstree theme? as my assets links are dynamic, i can't really hardcode any image files.

Comment: I've tried the approach used here, but it kind of doesnt work and I dont know why: https://code.google.com/p/jstree/issues/detail?id=681

Comment: Example code is from 2010 and seems outdated... look at the manual here; http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=$.jstree.defaults.contextmenu.items ":icon - a string, can be a path to an icon or a className, if using an image that is in the current directory use a ./ prefix, otherwise it will be detected as a class".
So you can use a (css) class or a path to an image.

Answer (score 0):

Use full path for the icon image, like this

icon: "/Content/images/deleteIcon.gif"